# How do I access custom html attributes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi im facing problem in this html document please help me

Im very new to this.

May be i am fool to missing something out.

I have put only useful source here to solve please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body id="owner_profile">
    <a id="buy" owner="789" token="1000" wrapper="purchase" name="oname">Hurray!</a><br>
    <script>
      document.write("You Have: ");
      document.write(document.getElementById('buy').token);
    </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I want it to display token but its giving undefined

**Result is :**

Hurray!

You Have: undefined

Answer (score 11):

There is a difference between attributes and properties. To get the attribute, use `getAttribute("token")`.

Many (predefined) attributes are mapped to properties (or the other way around, I don't know). So for example if you set a cell's `colSpan` property, you will also affect its `colspan` attribute.

However sometimes the two are very different. Most notably, the `value` attribute of an input will NOT change if you type in the box. However the `value` property will. This means that you can always reset a textbox with `elem.value = elem.getAttribute("value")`.

As a general rule, you should always use `get/setAttribute` to change an elements attributes, because you can't rely on the property being there.

Side-note: Those "attributes" should be data:

```
<a id="buy" data-owner="789" data-token="1000" data-wrapper="purchase" name="oname">
```

Comment: Also, [in most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset) you can access `data-`-attributes directly via `dataset` property. E.g. `document.getElementById('buy').dataset.token`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `.getAttribute('token')` instead of `.token`, since "token" isn't a valid HTML attribute.

```
<script>
document.write("You Have: ");
document.write(document.getElementById('buy').getAttribute("token"));
</script>
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AvKbn/

Comment: I'd word "not valid" as "custom" instead, yeah browsers don't know what to do with it and it doesn't pass W3C validator, but it's not like it breaks anything. Anyway, I'd recommend using a `data-` attribute for validness.