# Get custom field value on span element using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have something like this:

```
<span stylecode="123456789" class="punctis-social-widget"></span>
```

How can i get the stylecode value using javascript (not jquery). Also, is valid to use custom fields on spans?

Note: The field stylecode sometimes is not present, so the result of the function could be null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access custom html attributes in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328144/how-do-i-access-custom-html-attributes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not valid to use custom attributes.  If you need to store any values consider using the HTML5 `data` attribute.

```
<span id="item1" data-stylecode="123456789" class="punctis-social-widget"></span>
```

Then use JS to fetch that:

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById('item1');  // You could use class
    var sDataValue = element.getAttribute('data-stylecode');  //123456789
</script>
```

For jQuery fetch value with:

```
$('item1').data('stylecode');  //123456789
```

Comment: I haven't seen this before - aren't you making a 'custom attribute' called `data-stylecode` ?

Comment: @Plato, it's HTML 5, you define custom attributes using the "data" attribute.  The exact format is `data-#`, where `#` is replaced with the desired custom attribute name, then set to the desired string value.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you can select the span element, you can simply do this:

```
spanElem.getAttribute('stylecode');
```

If the attribute doesn't exists, `getAttribute()` will simply either return `null` or a `''` (seems to vary between browsers).

Selecting it would be easier if it had an id, in which case you could use `document.getElementById('id');` Otherwise you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('punctis-social-widget')` in newer standards-compliant browsers, or use `document.getElementsByTagName('span');` and loop over them and inspect their className properties.

As mentioned by Matthew, custom attributes are not valid (but usually don't cause any problems afaik), but provided you use HTML 5, turning it into a data-attribute will make it valid.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not good practice to use custom attributes like this, you can accomplish this task as such:

```
var apan = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var code = span[0].getAttribute('stylecode');
console.log(code);
```

Use the `data` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to catch the value of attribute :

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var stylecode = span.getAttribute("stylecode");
```

But I don't know about the second part of your question. Sorry.